# AngularJS component don't binding data

Tags: angularjs, components

HTML:

```
<form-control model="'myStringModel'"></form-control>
```

Component:

```
var formControl = function () {
return {
    templateUrl: 'Components/FormControl/views/FromControl-tml.html',

    controller: function () {
        console.log(this.model)
    },
    bindings: {
        model: '=',
    }
};
```

}

The output should be 'myStringModel' but i get 'undefined'.

Comment: How did you define your component? Do you use the `angular.module('myApp').component('formControl', {})` anywhere?

Comment: yes yes i do it